# Restrict Mysql User login from workbench, should connect to MYSQL from application only

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have two `MYSQL` users called Adam, Barry.

1. Adam user will connect to DB through application only[`java`, `hibernate`].
2. Barry user connects to DB through workbench or `MySQL` editor to perform
   DB operations like update, DB backup and etc.

Now, I want to restrict `Mysql` user Adam, He should connect DB through app only.
He should not connect to DB in any other form. welcome for any suggestions.

**I have tried** to add restrictions `MySQL` user, but I didn't get any proper solution.

**More Details:**

```
Application   : Java-based web application
DB server     : AWS Linux
MYSQL version : 8
```

Comment: what is the difference between the connection methods of workbench and application? I think they are all similar or same such as jdbc connection. Then how can you specify which access is coming from what application? I think it would be hard to recognize.

Comment: Don't give user A the password?

Answer (score 0):

When your application in official server,the server's IP is fixed,you can set IP for DB user A.

It can realize let user A connect db through server's IP only.

Hope this answer can help you,thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. Is there any alternative solutions ?

Comment: Sorry,I have no idea.